# Merge successive descendant nodes into one

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

**XML:**

```
<t>
  <ScreenSize>
    <Width>1440</Width>
    <Height>900</Height>
  </ScreenSize>
  <ConfigurationHotSpots>
    <Rectangle>
      <Location>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
      </Location>
      <Size>
        <Width>50</Width>
        <Height>50</Height>
      </Size>
      <X>0</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
      <Width>50</Width>
      <Height>50</Height>
    </Rectangle>
  </ConfigurationHotSpots>
</t>
```

**Desired Output XML:**

```
<t>
  <ScreenSizeWidth>1440</ScreenSizeWidth>
  <ScreenSizeWidth>900</ScreenSizeWidth>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationX>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationY>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeWidth>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeHeight>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleX>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleY>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleWidth>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleHeight>
</t>
```

**Rules:**

- For every element in a defined nodeset (in this case `<ScreenSize> | <ConfigurationHotSpots>`), do the following: process all leaf descendants (i.e., those without children) such that a new element is created; the name of this new element should be the concatenation of all elements between the current node and the childless descendant.
- There is a variable number of these "blocks" throughout the document, so no manual templates (i.e., one that processes only descendants of `<ScreenSize>`, one that processes only descendants of `<ConfigurationHotSpots>`, etc.)

**What I Currently Have:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ScreenSize|ConfigurationHotSpots">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*[not(*)]" mode="descendants" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="descendants">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(name(ancestor::*[not(self::t)]), name())}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem seems to be the `name(ancestor::*[not(self::t)])` portion; it's not doing what I would like it to be doing (magically outputting the names of those elements, one after another). Instead, this is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t>
  <ScreenSizeWidth>1440</ScreenSizeWidth>
  <ScreenSizeHeight>900</ScreenSizeHeight>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsX>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsY>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsWidth>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsHeight>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsX>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsY>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsWidth>
  <ConfigurationHotSpotsHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsHeight>
</t>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the transform rely upon the root element always being `t`? Can the transform rely upon the anchoring elements (in this case `ScreenSize|ConfigurationHotSpots`) always being the direct child of the root element? Or can they be in any level of the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `name(ancestor::*[not(self::t)])` will not return a list of names, but just the name of the last one it matches (or is it the first?).

A slightly different approach you can take, not that far off from what you are currently doing, is rather than jumping straight to the 'leaf' element, match each level in turn, but keep a running concatenation of the element names, which are passed from one level to anoter by parameters.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="ScreenSize|ConfigurationHotSpots">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="descendants">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="local-name()" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="descendants">
        <xsl:param name="name" />
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="descendants">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="concat($name, local-name())" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]" mode="descendants">
        <xsl:param name="name" />
        <xsl:element name="{concat($name, local-name())}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<t>
   <ScreenSizeWidth>1440</ScreenSizeWidth>
   <ScreenSizeHeight>900</ScreenSizeHeight>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationX>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationY>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeWidth>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeHeight>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleX>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleY>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleWidth>
   <ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleHeight>
</t>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is one of the shortest possible solutions**. It isn't as efficient as passing the accumulated path as parameter, but for not too-deeply nested structures this will not be significant:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[not(*) and (ancestor::ScreenSize or ancestor::ConfigurationHotSpots)]">

    <xsl:variable name="vName">
        <xsl:for-each select=
        "ancestor-or-self::*
           [not(descendant::*
                   [self::ScreenSize or self::ConfigurationHotSpots])
           ]">
           <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:element name="{$vName}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<t>
  <ScreenSize>
    <Width>1440</Width>
    <Height>900</Height>
  </ScreenSize>
  <ConfigurationHotSpots>
    <Rectangle>
      <Location>
        <X>0</X>
        <Y>0</Y>
      </Location>
      <Size>
        <Width>50</Width>
        <Height>50</Height>
      </Size>
      <X>0</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
      <Width>50</Width>
      <Height>50</Height>
    </Rectangle>
  </ConfigurationHotSpots>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ScreenSizeWidth>1440</ScreenSizeWidth>
<ScreenSizeHeight>900</ScreenSizeHeight>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationX>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleLocationY>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeWidth>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleSizeHeight>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleX>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleX>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleY>0</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleY>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleWidth>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleWidth>
<ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleHeight>50</ConfigurationHotSpotsRectangleHeight>
```

Comment: Given the OP's trial style-sheet, I think it is safe to rely on the root element being `t` and that the `ConfigurationHotSpots` and `ScreenSize` being children of `t`. If you factor in this additional data, there is room for substantial simplication in the predicate to `ancestor-or-self::*` .

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, He says that there will be different such elements at different height, so such "simplification" is undesirable.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - actually, I said that there would be different such "blocks" of elements to work with; I didn't fully consider @SeanBDurkin's claim, which, in fact, turns out to be correct: the root will always be `<t>` and the desired anchor elements (in this case, `<ConfigurationHotSpots>` and `<ScreenSize>`) will always be children of that root element. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @ABach, No need for apologies -- this actually helped produce a more general and universal solution :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - no need to update, but FYI, my desired result XML has the root element `<t>` still in place; your solution removes it.

Comment: @ABach, Yes, I know. As we both well know, generating the top element has no significance to the solution of the actual problem -- this is why I didn't care to include it -- any proficient XSLT programmer can do this almost mechanically.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tweak on Dimitre's solution. It is simpler and leverages off the known root element and known positions of the ScreenSize etc., as per OP's comments...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]
                       [ancestor::ScreenSize|ancestor::ConfigurationHotSpots]">   
    <xsl:variable name="vName">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[not(self::t)]">
           <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:element name="{$vName}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Here is an alternate form of the match condition...

```
 <xsl:template match="(ScreenSize//* | ConfigurationHotSpots//*)[not(*)]">
```

I'm not actually sure which is better. If performance isn't a big deal, go with which ever reads easier. Just beware that this means two whole document scans for each template match attempt.

Comment: +1 Great solution - thank you. FYI, the one small issue is that this transformation removes the root node `<t>` from the output.

Comment: @SeanBDurkin - yes, please. After all, we want the XML document to be well-formed, right? :)

Comment: Sure. Unless this output is just a fragment of a bigger picture. As an aside, it is a strange thing that the XDM model allows for multiple root nodes in the output.

Comment: Also note: In this context, it is better to use local-name() instead of name(). If one name was prefixed, it would invalidate our output element name.

Comment: @SeanBDurkin - absolutely, that makes sense. Thank you! P.S. I agree that the multiple-root-node allowance is odd...