# XSLT script to get rid of nested child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Input XML:

```
<tree>
  <node name="GrandParent">
    <node name="Parent1">
      <qualifier>Fat</qualifier>
    </node>
    <node name="Parent2">
      <qualifier>Slim</qualifier>
      <node name="Child1">
        <qualifier>Tall</qualifier>
      </node>
      <node name="Child2">
        <qualifier>Short</qualifier>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>
</tree>
```

Required output:

```
<tree>
  <node name="GrandParent-Parent1">
    <qualifier>Fat</qualifier>
  </node>
  <node name="GrandParent-Parent2">
    <qualifier>Slim</qualifier>
  </node>
  <node name="GrandParent-Parent2-Child1">
    <qualifier>Tall</qualifier>
  </node>
  <node name="GrandParent-Parent2-Child2">
    <qualifier>Short</qualifier>
  </node>
</tree>
```

I want to get an optimized XSLT script for achieving the same. Please help me.

(Note: The input given is just a sample. The child nodes can be nested to any depth. )

Comment: Please show the XSLT stylesheet that you are having problems with.

Comment: I dont have any XSLT scripts with me now :(
I am just a beginner. If you can, please help me.

Comment: I am searching. I tried some small examples also. But i have to make this work done tommorow itself.
Thats why i am asking help from some experts.
Dont misunderstand me.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints to point you in the right direction:

- Get to know the `<xsl:template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>` instructions; they will be the backbone of a solution for this problem.
- Get to know the `concat()' function, as well. This will assist with the naming scheme change you are looking to make.
- Become comfortable with XPath axes (in particular, `parent::*`, `ancestor::*`, and relative XPaths like `../` or `../../`.

Additionally, take a look at this question (and subsequent answers) - it might be useful in your scenario, as well: [Merge successive descendant nodes into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396123/merge-successive-descendant-nodes-into-one)

It sounds like you have a hard deadline tomorrow, but going forward, I would recommend taking the time to read good materials on XSLT/XPath. You can find several here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: @IntelligentYahoo - I've updated my answer with a bit more in the way of practical help.

Comment: again thanx ABach..Hope i can find the solution soon :) :)

Comment: @IntelligentYahoo - feel free to ask additional questions. As you attempt to solve the solution yourself, we can be here to guide you should you get stuck.